# Save Eclipse Plugin project state and configurations

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, eclipse-rcp

I have an eclipse plugin project that is basically a GUI to visualize data from external source.

I want to give the user the option to save the current configurations of the plugin project, i.e. which views are opened, current data being analysed and the values placed as input in the different views (JTextboxes etc.).

Thus the user may load the file to the restart the project from the last configuration.

Does such a save mechanism of the plugin project exist? Specially loading the project with previous views from the load file.

Answer (score 0):

Views implement `IPersistable` so you can implement the `saveState` method:

```
@Override
public void saveState(IMemento memento)
{
  memento.putString("key", "value");

  ....
}
```

override the `ViewPart` `init` method to restore the data saved in the memento:

```
@Override
public void init(IViewSite site, IMemento memento)
{
  super.init(site, memento);

  String value = memento.getString("key");

  ...
}
```

I am assuming you are doing a 3.x style RCP (using `ViewPart`), for an e4 RCP different code is required.

Comment: You are right, I am using the ViewPart. Thanks for the answer, I will try it out and let you know.